# Incoming email stops working after website migration of G Suite from a shared hosting environment to a Digital Ocean VPS

Tags: email, dns

I was using Google’s G Suite for my company email address from shared hosting. Recently I have changed my web hosting to Digital Ocean (VPS). So the email stopped working with the new server.

I just want to use the same G Suite account for my new hosting.
I was thinking If I should just add MX Records in the Digital Ocean.

So I just added G Suite’s MX record into Digital Ocean. Incoming emails are not working but Outgoing emails working. Not sure if I have to do any other thing within Digital Ocean to make it work.

Comment: Solved: Actually It was just a propagation delay. I just had to add Mx Records and It started working after a few hours. Thanks.